# No applicable method for 'anti_join' applied to an object of class "factor"

Tags: r, dataframe, comparison, dplyr, anti-join

I want to Identify the rows present in dataframe1 which are not present in dataframe2 based on a particular column. I have used the below code to get the desired information.

```
diffId <- anti_join(dat$ID,datwe$ID)
```

Unfortunately, I have encountered with an error:

> Error in UseMethod("anti_join") :
>   no applicable method for 'anti_join' applied to an object of class "factor"

I have checked the class of the desired column in both the dataframes and which turned out to be `factor`. Have also tried to separate the column into a separate variable in an assumption that it might solve the issue, but of no luck !

```
fac1 <- datwe$ID
fac2 <- dat$ID
diffId <- anti_join(fac2,fac1)
```

Could you please share your thoughts ?

Thanks

Comment: The correct tag is data.frame not dataframes, fyi. (I already edited it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost all `dplyr` functions operate on `tbls` (depending on the context it can be `data.frame`, `data.table`, database connection and so on) so what you really want is something like this:

```
> dat <- data.frame(ID=c(1, 3, 6, 4), x=runif(4))
> datwe <- data.frame(ID=c(3, 5, 8), y=runif(3))
> anti_join(dat, datwe, by='ID') %>% select(ID)
  ID
1  4
2  6
3  1
```

Note that ordering is clearly not preserved.

If you use factors (unlike numerics in the example above) with different levels there is a conversion between `factor` and `character` involved.

If you want to operate on vectors then you can use `setdiff` (available in both `base` and `dplyr`)

```
> setdiff(dat$ID, datwe$ID)
[1] 1 6 4
```

Comment: Thanks @zero323. It worked with the above suggestion. (I will keep this thread open for a while to learn other methods of doing this task and mark  this one as answer) 

Could you be kind to explain why it didn't work when there was only one column ?

Comment: It works perfectly if there is only one column. Problem is `dat$ID` is  no longer a `data.frame` but a vector.

Comment: Oh, `anti_join` can be used only for `data.frame`. Thanks !

Comment: To be precise on the objects that can be coerced to `dplyr::tbl`.